# How do I create a public_html structure on apache localhost?

Tags: apache, configuration, localhost, directory-structure, public-html

I want it such that when I type "localhost/websiteName/" on my local machine I would be served "localhost/websiteName/public_html/".

Is this possible ? Or am I missing something here ?

I also want to make everything outside public_html inaccessible.